# Node JS, Cheerio, getting XML version

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xslt, cheerio

I have a XML with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="25-1.xsl"?>

<movies>
    <movie id="1">
    <title>Matrix</title>
    <characters>
        <character>
             <name>Tomas Anderson</name>
             <actor>Keanu Reeves</actor>
        </character>
    </characters>
    <plot>
        Action
    </plot>
    <rating type="stars">5</rating>
    </movie>
<movies>
```

I'm using `cheerio` lib to access DOM of this XML and I know how to get values from tags.

However, I dont know how to get and change data from `<xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251">` `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="25-1.xsl"?>`

Is it even possbile to access to these intruction tags by cheerio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested multiple xml parsers (`x2js`, `xml-js`, `xml-parser`) and none of them seems to be able to parse the `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` tag.
For some of them, trying to parse this tag result in a failure to parse the whole XML.

So I choose this one : [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)

Here is how you can make it work :

```
var convert = require('xml-js'); 
var converted = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 2});
console.log(JSON.parse(converted));
```

It gives you informations about the `<?xml ... ?>` tag like that :

```
{ _declaration: { _attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'windows-1251' } }, ... }
```

So, to solve the problem of the `xml-stylesheet` tag, you can take this little piece of code to parse all these tags from your xml :

```
var styleSheets = xml.match(/<\?xml-stylesheet.*\?>/g);
var arrayCSS = styleSheets.map(css => {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    var tmp1 = css.split('?').splice(1,1);
    var tmp2 = tmp1[0].split(' ');
    tmp2.splice(0, 1);
    return tmp2.reduce((acc, el) => {
        var arr = el.split('=');
        acc[arr[0]] = arr[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
        return acc;
    }, {});
});
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards

Comment: Very interesting approach. However, not having a library for getting instruction tags of xml for javascript is very disappointing. PHP got `DOMDocument` class, which can do it in one line.